# Google Docs Remove Title and Footer

Tags: embed, spreadsheet, google-docs

I'm trying to embed a Google Docs sheet into my website, however, I am having a problem getting rid of the title bar and the footer.  I want to just embed a range of cells and nothing else.  Does anyone have a solution to this?  I have tried "chrome=false" and "widget=false" within my iframe to no avail.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

My iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRAQLoHO6TOpu7Sh5M3DwUoHt_eh-dWb-fHAB6Jn5rRtbxJSGsKbXuw3C6nmC_FTqzSiSmLWStRrrDT/pubhtml?gid=0&range=a1:l28";single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false; width="1000" height="600;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input.  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that your parameter is correct. But please use the parameter as the query parameters for the endpoint as follows.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRAQLoHO6TOpu7Sh5M3DwUoHt_eh-dWb-fHAB6Jn5rRtbxJSGsKbXuw3C6nmC_FTqzSiSmLWStRrrDT/pubhtml?gid=0&range=a1:l28&widget=false&headers=false&chrome=false" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>
```

#### Reference:

- [Make Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms public](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en)

> **Edit embedded spreadsheets**
>
> - gid=: The sheet ID.
> - range=: The rows and columns that are published to the web. For example, A1:B14.
> - widget=: True or false. If true, the sheet tab is displayed at the bottom.
> - headers=: True or false. If true, row numbers and column letters are displayed.
> - chrome=: True or false. If true, the title and footer are displayed.

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.